# Quartus II: Suppress warnings by Verilog module

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

In my FPGA project I use the Quartus II PCIe megafunction. The number of warning messages this Altera library module produces baffles me.

Is there a way to have Quartus II suppress all the warnings messages generated from within the PCIe megafunction top-level module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on a warning message, then go to "suppress", then choose between various "quick" suppress options or pop open the [Message Suppression Manager](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/report/msw/msw_db_suppression_manager.htm) that allows you to visualize, edit, import and export all the rules you want.

As OP says in the comments below you can also use the * wildcard, so to suppress all pcie messages he wrote `*pcie*` and that did the trick.

Comment: That allows for message level suppression, not module level suppression.

Comment: I believe you can add a string match throwing in the module name, thus suppressing all warnings associated with it. Not sure about regular expressions or whatever though...

Comment: have a look here: http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.0/mergedProjects/report/msw/msw_db_suppression_manager.htm

Comment: I ended up using the `*` wildcard. So to suppress all pcie messages I suppressed the expression `*pcie*`.

Comment: Thanks for the comeback, I added your solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know how Quartus manages the message suppression:
The suppression specifications when created through the GUI are saved in a .srf file.
Add this file (*.srf) in your source control system if you are using one.
You may also edit the file directly if you prefer.

```
{ "" "" "" "*" {  } {  } 0 292013 "" 0 0 "Design Software" 0 -1 0 ""}
{ "" "" "" "*altera_merlin_*" {  } {  } 0 9999 "" 0 0 "Design Software" 0 -1 0 ""}
```

The above example lines suppress the message

```
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license.
```

as well as all warning messages containing `*altera_merlin_*`